# Difference between “pardon”, “excusez-moi” and “désolé”

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques, politesse

I recently came back from Paris and while there if someone happened to bump me they would say '*pardon*' instead of '*désolé*' or '*excusez-moi*' as I was taught to say in French classes.

My understanding is that '*excusez-moi*' is used in preparation for a question, '*désolé*' is used with sincerest apologies and '*pardon*' is a request to be excused from a simple mistake or to move past someone in a crowd.

Is this correct?

Comment: Reminds me of an early encounter with French at a hotel in Québec... A little girl running down the hall bumped into me and squeaked two syllables: "Scusez!"

Comment: I've spent some time in Paris and Montréal recently and found that in the "moving past someone in a crowd" or "accidentally bumped someone" situations that I heard _pardon_ much more frequently in Paris and _excusez-moi_ much more in Montréal. That's my only observation here!

Comment: @Hunter Thats interesting. I was thinking that my inclination to say *excusez-moi* was due to my natural english language coming through

Comment: @Hunter Yes, and the obvious reason for that is that Excusez-moi is a direct translation of excuse me. Anyway, désolée is means sorry, And is used like sorry would be used in English. [please use caps for names of languages in English. Thanks.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a French, I would say "pardon" as a quick form of apology rather than the other forms. It plays me trick when I speak in English when I would naturally say "pardon" rather than "excuse me".

"Désolé" works as a sincere apology in the complete form: "Je suis désolé", else it is slightly less formal than "Pardon".

As for "Excusez-moi" it is probably ok in Canada . But in France-French I perceive it as less formal than "pardon". The correct form is "Veuillez m'excuser" which you can use as a formal way to barge in front of people or prepare for a request.

Comment: *Excusez-moi* is rude?? Maybe are you thinking about the controversial *je m'excuse*?

Comment: I said "I perceive", but you are right it is not rude. I will update my answe.

Comment: @jlliagre do you agree that *veuillez m'excuser* is preferred over *excusez-moi* ?

Comment: @Aerovistae That depends. *Veuillez m'excuser* is more formal (but less than *je vous prie de bien vouloir accepter mes excuses*), is rare in spoken French, is more likely to introduce a clause (e.g. *Veuillez m'excuser de vous répondre avec avec retard*) while *excusez-moi* is common in spoken French where it is more likely to be a standalone request. Coluche wrote the now famous *excusez-moi de vous demander pardon.* ;-)

Comment: Thanks @A.P. im aware that there will alway be differences between dialects but your answer helped clear up my question that was directly about Paris, France.

Comment: I am agree with @A.P. . "Excusez moi" is "rude" because it's an "impératif". We use the tense "Impératif" for order usually.

Answer (score 1):

There is a big difference between the two :

— « *Désolé* » simply expresses your personal feeling about something. You feel bad that something happened to someone.

— « *Je m'excuse* » means that you accept responsibility for the error or the situation for which you express your regrets, the fault lies with you.

Dire *désolé* exprime simplement vos sentiments personnels à propos de quelque chose.
*S'excuser* implique que vous acceptez la responsabilité de la faute ou de l'erreur et que vous exprimez vos regrets à ce sujet.

Comment: No one is saying that désolée is sorry. Je suis désolé, I'm sorry.  Je m'excuse can also be I apologize.